# Faster implementation of Math.round?

Tags: java, math, rounding, micro-optimization

Are there any drawbacks to this code, which appears to be a faster (and correct) version of `java.lang.Math.round`?

```
public static long round(double d) {

    if (d > 0) {
        return (long) (d + 0.5d);
    } else {
        return (long) (d - 0.5d);
    }
}
```

It takes advantage of the fact that, in Java, truncating to long rounds in to zero.

Comment: @TrueWill: If it's neatly in a function that's properly named... Would it really matter? Perhaps it's being used in a math-intensive program.

Comment: It would be rare that you would find a significantly faster way of doing something for a method that has been around since 1.0 while maintaining 100% consistency with the original method.

Comment: Absolutely is a micro-optimization, and in a local sense was worth it.  -- but these are not recommended for general use.

Comment: It's NOT a senseless optimization. I have an algorithm that depends heavily on `Math.round` and this helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are some [special cases](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29) which the built in method handles, which your code does not handle. From the documentation:

- If the argument is `NaN`, the result is 0.
- If the argument is negative infinity or any value less than or equal to the value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the result is equal to the value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.
- If the argument is positive infinity or any value greater than or
  equal to the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, the result is equal to the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 6):

I've been testing this, and there is one key potential drawback which has not yet been described here: You are changing the [rounding tie-breaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking) method.

`Math.round()` implements the "round half up" rule, whereas your `round()` method implements the "round half away from zero" rule.

For example:

- `Math.round(-0.5d)` => `0L`
- `Your.round(-0.5d)` => `-1L`

This may or may not be a problem for you, but you should understand that the above method is not a drop-in replacement for `Math.round()`, even after the NaN and infinity considerations already outlined.

Another relevant question: [Rounding negative numbers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269721/rounding-negative-numbers-in-java)

As for the performance, there is no doubt that the above method is significantly faster than `Math.round()` - it runs in about 35% of the time for randomly generated positive and negative values. This can be a worthwhile optimisation when calling this method in a tight loop. It's even better (25% of the runtime) when given only positive values, possibly because of the CPU using [branch prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predication).

`Math.round()` is ultimately implemented by a native JNI call, which might be the cause of the performance difference. [This Sun/Oracle bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6908131) suggests there might be pure-Java version in j6u22, but I can't see where, and indeed `Math.round()` in j6u23 performs similarly to j6u16 in my tests. I have not tested on other versions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes; you're not accounting for underflow or overflow. Pragmatically speaking, this may not matter for your application.