# Why does Java's RoundingMode HALF_UP round -2.5 to -3?

Tags: java, rounding

RoundingMode allows the programmer to specify in what manner floating point numbers are to be rounded. This is great and all, but there is this one thing about it I found peculiar. Maybe I just misunderstood something fundamental at school.

But this rounding mode is described as the one I was taught at school, "Always round to the nearest number, and when dead in the center, always round up.", but why does it round -2.5 to -3?

I conclude as much that it rounds up in terms of absolute values, but -2 is, to me, certainly "up" from -2.5.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269721/rounding-negative-numbers-in-java

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html Take a look at this. This might help you to find the method you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RoundingMode.UP` is the rounding mode for "away from zero."  `RoundingMode.FLOOR` is towards negative infinity, and `CEILING` is towards positive infinity.  `HALF_UP` is consistent with `UP` when the fractional part is exactly 0.5.

They had to choose *some* term to mean "away from zero."

Answer (score 3):

The rationale is outlined in the JavaDocs for [RoundingMode.HALF_UP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP).

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up. Behaves as for RoundingMode.UP if the discarded fraction is >= 0.5; otherwise, behaves as for RoundingMode.DOWN. Note that this is the rounding mode commonly taught at school.

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up) article about Rounding methods makes a different claim:

> For example, by this rule the value 23.5 gets rounded to 24, but −23.5 gets rounded to −23.
>
> This is one of two rules generally taught in US elementary mathematics classes.

Though a citation has been requested.

Comment: The OP's real issue seems to be the misconception that `RoundingMode.UP` is meant to be interpreted as "towards positive infinity," which is not addressed in this answer currently.