# Python style round() in Java

Tags: java, python, rounding

I'm seeing differences between the built in `round()` function in Python and Java's `java.lang.Math.round()` function.

In Python we see..

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> round(0.0)
0.0
>>> round(0.5)
1.0
>>> round(-0.5)
-1.0
```

And in Java..

```
System.out.println("a: " + Math.round(0.0));
System.out.println("b: " + Math.round(0.5));
System.out.println("c: " + Math.round(-0.5));
```

> a: 0
>   b: 1
>   c: 0

Looks like Java is always *rounding up* while Python *rounds down* for negative numbers.

What's the best way to get Python style rounding behavior in Java?

Comment: Related question but without a proposed solution: [Rounding negative numbers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269721/rounding-negative-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way:

```
public static long symmetricRound( double d ) {
    return d < 0 ? - Math.round( -d ) : Math.round( d );
}
```

If the number is negative, round its positive value, then negate the result. If it's positive or zero, just use `Math.round()` as is.

Comment: Shame there's nothing built in. At least this is clean and readable. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe try:

```
float a = -0.5;
signum(a)*round(abs(a));
```

Comment: It will be good if you add a few words explanation to your answer

Comment: Not to be deliberately unhelpful, but I think it is reasonable to expect someone to work out why this works themselves. If you are unfamiliar with any of the the methods they are all in the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

Answer (score 1):

The round() function in Python and java works completely different.

In java, we use the normal mathematical calculation for rounding up the value

```
import java.lang.*;
public class HelloWorld{
        public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(Math.round(0.5));
        System.out.println(Math.round(1.5));
        System.out.println(Math.round(-0.5));
        System.out.println(Math.round(-1.5));
        System.out.println(Math.round(4.5));
        System.out.println(Math.round(3.5));
     }
}
$javac HelloWorld.java
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloWorld
1
2
0
-1
5
4
```

But in Python, for odd numbers the answer is rounded up to even numbers whereas when the number is even then no rounding up takes place.

```
>>> round(0.5)
0
>>> round(1.5)
2
>>> round(-0.5)
0
>>> round(-1.5)
-2
>>> round(4.5)
4
>>> round(3.5)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your own round method:

```
public static double round(double n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return -1 * Math.round(-1 * n);
    }

    if (n >= 0) {
        return Math.round(n);
    }
}
```