# How do I make it so that negative numbers round down?

Tags: java

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269721/rounding-negative-numbers-in-java),

> Returns the closest long to the argument. The result is rounded to an integer by adding 1/2, taking the floor of the result, and casting the result to type long. In other words, the result is equal to the value of the expression:
>
> `(long)Math.floor(a + 0.5d)`

Which, means, it rounds up.

How do I make it round down?

Comment: You won't be able to change the rounding behavior of Math.round(). But this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/269971/2615897 from the same question suggests using BigDecimal which does have rounding modes, so you could use that. Or you could make a custom function.

Comment: If you want different rounding for primitives, you are going to have to implement it on your own.

Comment: Can't you just use `Math.floor(yourNumberHere);` ?

Comment: Just add a *-1* ! :)